# Closing the dropdown button programmatically

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I am using this zurb-foundation dropdown button - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown_buttons.html

But I have an additional requirement to close the dropdown list when a user clicks outside the dropdown button itself or when the user clicks on an item in the dropdown list, so I need a way to programmatically close an open dropdown list on an on-click event.

What's the javascript call I need to make to programmatically close an open dropdown list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some searching here is a slightly cleaner way of doing it:

```
Foundation.libs.dropdown.close($('#id_of_dropdown_list'));
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as it seems to be the official way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but this worked for me.

```
$(document).foundation('dropdown', 'close', $('.f-dropdown'));
```

Answer (score 3):

In Foundation 6.2, you can do something like:

```
$('.dropdown-pane').foundation('close');
```

For reference: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html#close

Answer (score 2):

With Foundation 6.3.0 if you want to close the dropdown list when you click outside the dropdown button, just add the data attribute `data-close-on-click="true"` in the dropdown pane. I have this in my code:

```
<div class="small warning button-group">
    <a class="dropdown button arrow-only float-right" data-toggle="dropdown-menu-1">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Show menu</span>
    </a>
    <a class="button float-right" href="/vacancies/show">View</a>

    <div class="dropdown-pane bottom" id="dropdown-menu-1" data-dropdown data-close-on-click="true">
        <a href="">Edit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

More: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html#js-options

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:-

```
$("#id_of_dropdown").removeClass("open").css("left", "-99999px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need the data-dropdown-content attribute attached to the dropdown ul element.

Reference: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1831#issuecomment-15133817

Answer (score 0):

The programmatic methods close/open/toggle exist for the `Dropdown` element, as you can see [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html#close).
These can be triggered [as suggested by allicarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665565/5950626).

However for the `DropdownMenu` element, no close/open methods exist. In case anyone needs those, you can simulate the opening/closing click:

```
document.querySelector('.dropdown .value').click()
```